# How to get array elements from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to extract an array from my json string. Please help me. I have the following javascript code,

```
function lookup(inputString,autoSuggestionsList,TextFieldName)
{
   autoSuggestionsListMain=autoSuggestionsList;
   inputTextField=TextFieldName;
   if(inputString.length == 0)
   {
      $('#suggestions').hide();
   }
   else
   {
      $.post("show_location_hint.php", 
            { queryString: ""+inputString+"" }, 
            function(data) { if(data.length >0) {  } });
   }
}
```

my show_location_hint.php file will echo the following json string

```
{"root": {"success":"1","message":"","data":{"locations":[a,b,c]}}}
```

how can I get the elements from the array locations?
please help me
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using the console to check how your object is built up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it to an array using `JSON.parse()`:

`var dataArray = JSON.parse(jsonString)`

Then just simply do stuff like:

`alert(dataArray.root.message)`

Comment: There is no need to parse as jQuery will do that for you upon determining the type of the response.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Whenever you have an array, you can obviously do this: `myArrayVariable.push(dataArray.root.data.locations)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.post("show_location_hint.php", { queryString: inputString }, function(data) {
    if (data) {
        var locations = data.root.data.locations;
    }
});
```

Note however that your JSON format is not valid as, `a`, `b`, and `c` should be wrapped in double quotes. I'm guessing this is just a sample of your actual data though.

Comment: Unless he is using some legacy jQuery version, which doesn't auto-parse assumed JSON strings.

Comment: It he's using a version of jQuery older than 1.5.1 then he has bigger issues to solve before this.

Comment: @jAndy ;) ... blah blah character limit

Answer (score 0):

First your json is well formed. It should be:

```
{"root": {"success":"1","message":"","data":{"locations":["a","b","c"]}}}
```

and you can get data like this using jQuery:

```
var data = {"root": {"success":"1","message":"","data":{"locations":["a","b","c"]}}};

console.log(data.root);

console.log(data.root.success);

console.log(data.root.data);

$.each(data.root.data,function(index,item){

       console.log(item);

       });
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5RR9/)